# How to operate a SwitchBoard that turns on the following switches within a sequence n? Python 3x

Tags: python, object, loops, boolean

I wand to build a class SwitchBoard with the following properties:

- when I create a switchboard, I should be able to set the number of switches it contains
  all switches should start in the "off" position
- if I print a switchboard, it should print something along the lines of: "The following switches are on: 1 3 5 7 9"
- if I call switch(n) with n as an integer, it should ip the status of the n'th lightswitch
- if I call switch every(n) with n as an integer, it should ip the status of every n'th lightswitch

**I should be able to write a piece of global code that solves the lightswitch problem as stated above.**

This is my work so far, the first is class `LightSwitch`

- If switch is ON, it will flip and turn it OFF
- If switch is OFF, it will flip and turn it ON

```
class LightSwitch():

    def __init__(self, mode):
            self.switch = mode

    def __str__(self):
        if self.switch == True:
            return ("I am on")

        if self.switch == False:
            return ("I am off")        

    def turn_on(self):
        self.switch = True

    def turn_off(self):
        self.switch = False

    def flip(self):
        if self.switch == True:
            self.switch = False
        else:
            self.switch = True
```

And for the class `SwitchBoard`, this is what I have:

```
class SwitchBoard():

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.switches = []
        for i in range(n):
            self.switches.append(LightSwitch(False))

    def switch(self, n):
        self.switches[n].flip()

    def switch_every(self, n):
        for i in range(0,len(self.switches), n):
            switch(i)

    def __str__(self):
        return "The following switches are on: " + str(self.switches)


if __name__ == ('__main__'):

    my_light = LightSwitch(False)
    my_light.flip()
    print (my_light) # This prints "I am on"

    my_light2 = LightSwitch(True)
    my_light2.flip()
    print(my_light2) # This prints "I am off"

    my_switchboard = SwitchBoard(10) # This is the issue.
    my_switchboard.switch_every(2)
    print (my_switchboard)
```

This isn't working out, I'm using a list to append the number of OFF switches but I'm not sure how to write global code to solve this issue, such as turning on switches within a sequence, or maybe something is missing, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call the method `switch`, use `self.switch(i)` not `switch(i)`:

```
def switch_every(self, n):
    for i in range(0,len(self.switches), n):
        self.switch(i)   # <-- Change here
```

---

To get some readable output when you call

```
 print (my_switchboard)
```

change the `LightSwitch.__str__` method to `LightSwitch.__repr__`:

```
 def __repr__(self):   # <-- Change `__str__` to `__repr__`
     if self.switch == True:
         return "I am on"

     if self.switch == False:
         return "I am off"
```

This is because, when you print a list, the `repr` of its contents are printed.

---

The `LightSwitch.flip` method could be shortened to:

```
 def flip(self):
     self.switch = False if self.switch else True
```

using a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

Comment: In the SwitchBoard class I wanted to append integers into the list not strings, say, I flip every third switch, starting at 0.
So I flip switches 0,3,6,9,12,...
that is, if a switch is on, I flip it to off.
If a switch is off, I flip it to on. Not ['I am on', 'I am off'.. and so on] I keep on getting an error with __main__